# pgfplot gives me "could not parse input " as a floating point number, sorry."

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying to create a plot, and while I am very new to LaTeX, I feel like I've gotten a good feel for it. However, I cannot seem to fix this error:

```
Package PGF Math Error: Could not parse input " as a floating point number, sorry. The unreadable part was near "..
```

I have tried for 2 hours now, to find any solutions to no avail. Can anyone guide me?

Here is my code:

```
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[width=13cm,height=6cm,
    title={something},
    ylabel={rente i \%},
    xmin=1988, xmax=2019,
    ymin=-2.0, ymax=12.0,
    xtick={1989,1992,1995,1998,2001,2004,2007,2010,2013,2017},
    ytick={0.0,2.5,5.0,7.5,10.0,},
    xticklabel style={/pgf/number format/1000 sep=,rotate=60,anchor=east,font=\normalsize},
    legend pos=north east,
    ymajorgrids=true,
    grid style=dashed,
]

\addplot[
    color=black,
    mark=pentagon*,
    ]
  coordinates {
(1989,9.9)
(1990,9.7)
(1991,10.6)
(1992,9.3)
(1993,9.0)
(1994,7.3)
(1995,7.9)
(1996,8.3)
(1997,6.3)
(1998,5.0)
(1999,4.9)
(2000,5.7)
(2001,5.1)
(2002,5.1)
(2003,4.3)
(2004,4.3)
(2005,3.4)
(2006,3.8)
(2007,4.3)
(2008,4.2)
(2009,3.6)
(2010,2.9)
(2011,2.7)
(2012,1.4)
(2013,1.7)
(2014,1.9)
(2015,0.5)
(2016,0.3)
(2017,0.4)

};
    \legend{10-årig statsobligation}    

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture} \\
\end{center}
```

Comment: LaTeX errors are not alway easy to guess the meaning of -but you can always uncomment lines until you have a bare minimum that works -and from there slowly find the line and exact thing that is causing the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`pgfplots` is expecting another number in a list. Change `ytick={0.0,2.5,5.0,7.5,10.0,}` to `ytick={0.0,2.5,5.0,7.5,10.0}` (remove the comma before the `}`).